# Error with jGrasp and MinGW - Cannot compile - code 0xc000007b

Tags: java, c, windows, dll, jgrasp

I had a Windows 7 computer, where I wrote C programs with jGrasp. After switching to Windows 10 I installed jGrasp, MinGW (including g++), and Java. I set my PATH to the MinGW bin and the Java jre bin. When I open code that used to compile perfectly, it now doesn't compile. I get the following error...

cc1.exe - Application error
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

I go to the MinGW bin and find cc1.exe, and double click it. I get 3 error messages saying the program can't start because .dll files are missing. The missing .dll files are libgmp-10.dll, libmpc-3.dll, and libmpfr-4.dll . All of these are in the MinGW bin directory, so I have no idea what's wrong.

Research online shows this problem might be the result of mixing 32-bit and 64-bit tools. I have a 64-bit version of Windows 10. I used the MinGW installer though, and was not given a choice of 32 or 64. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I just want to code!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the MinGW bin directory to my path.  With that, the error was fixed.

I was invoking MinGW with a fully qualified path to the .exe file.

I don't know why MinGW didn't find the .dlls in the directory explicitly named for the .exe.